# Cakephp sending emails with DKIM signature

Tags: cakephp, dkim

My server emails are considered SPAM by Google and Yahoo and I have been told that I need to use DKIM with my cakephp when my server sends emails, below is my current code, what else do I need to add?

```
$email = $user['User']['email'];

    $verify_link = Router::url('/', true).'user/welcome/'.base64_encode($id).'/'.base64_encode($email);         
                $message = "Hello $name,<br/><br/>Welcome to our domain";


        $Email = new CakeEmail();
                    $Email->from(array($site_sender_email => 'Ourdomain'));
                    $Email->to($email);
                    $Email->subject('Welcome to our domain');
                    $Email->emailFormat('html');
                    $Email->send($message);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not about your code. It is about the email address and the server you are sending email from. You may have to configure your server.

Have you tried reading about DKIM?

http://www.dkim.org/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail

Comment: Yes, and I have enabled DKIM on my server. CPanel keeps telling me the code should enable it. I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Peshraw, how can I make my server using PHP mail script send the email through the SMTP service to another external email hosting domain.